What is the best approach to indexing in Postgres (or any other SQL DB)
I have the following query:
SELECT
    id,
    RANK() OVER (
      PARTITION BY user_id
      ORDER BY
        effective_date <= '${date}' DESC,
        effective_date DESC,
        created_at DESC
    ) AS rank
FROM $table WHERE company_id = $companyId AND effective_date <= $date;

I want to add an index on the table to speed the performance of the query.
My guess is having a composite index on (company_id, effective_date) would help. However I wanted also to add the user_id column as part of an index.
So my question is: Should I use a single index on (company_id, effective_date, user_id)? Will having the userId as the last part of the composite index help the performance of PARTITION BY user_id OR should I add a separate index on UserID only? Or it does not matter as it will not help at all?
Also worth mentioning: there are also a few queries that do not use ranks and partition and the where filter is applied only on company_id and user_id. For that case the best index option would be (company_id, user_id). However the most of the time the first query is used, so improving the performance of that query would be the most important thing to achieve.
The output of EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS) while having an index on (company_id, effective_date, user_id):
WindowAgg  (cost=35.39..36.91 rows=55 width=29) (actual time=0.396..0.596 rows=56 loops=1)
  Output: id, rank() OVER (?), ((effective_date <= '2025-05-30'::date)), effective_date, created_at, user_id
  Buffers: shared hit=5
  ->  Sort  (cost=35.39..35.53 rows=55 width=21) (actual time=0.342..0.352 rows=56 loops=1)
        Output: ((effective_date <= '2025-05-30'::date)), effective_date, created_at, user_id, id
        Sort Key: user_role.user_id, ((user_role.effective_date <= '2025-05-30'::date)) DESC, user_role.effective_date DESC, user_role.created_at DESC
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 29kB
        Buffers: shared hit=5
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.user_role  (cost=4.84..33.80 rows=55 width=21) (actual time=0.223..0.273 rows=56 loops=1)
              Output: (effective_date <= '2025-05-30'::date), effective_date, created_at, user_id, id
              Recheck Cond: ((user_role.company_id = 47) AND (user_role.effective_date <= '2025-05-30'::date))
              Heap Blocks: exact=3
              Buffers: shared hit=5
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on user_role__company_id_effective_date_user_id_idx  (cost=0.00..4.83 rows=55 width=0) (actual time=0.170..0.171 rows=56 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: ((user_role.company_id = 47) AND (user_role.effective_date <= '2025-05-30'::date))
                    Buffers: shared hit=2
Settings: jit = 'off'
Planning Time: 0.959 ms
Execution Time: 0.785 ms


Have you tried adding the different indices and then checking the query execution plan with each one? It's a great way to explore and learn. If you come across behaviour that differs from what you expect, then you can then ask a much more specific question.

@user1191247 yes, I tested a few options, in all cases I get similar performance, and when I run the query with explain analyze I always get:
Sort Key: user_id, ((effective_date <= '2024-05-30'::date)) DESC, effective_date DESC, created_at DESC"
and
Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 29kB"
the filtering on the where clause is always the same. However I don't know if there is any benefit on having the user_id in the index.
It also may be that my data sample is not big enough to test the queries and to see differences in performance.

Could you please share the results from explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for this query? In plain text.

@FrankHeikens I updated the description with the output of the query.

Execution Time: 0.785 ms, that's going to be close to perfection! For now I wouldn't spend any more time on this query, this one is fast en most likely fast enough for now.

It's tagged [mysql]; either remove that tag or add EXPLAIN (etc) for that RDBMS.

@RickJames the title is "What is the best approach to indexing in Postgres (or any other SQL DB)". I am more interested in knowing how the index works in such a query regardless of the DB rather than in knowing the postgres specific approach.

There are quite likely to be incompatible differences of INDEX implementation among the various RDBMSs.  I would guess that INDEX(company_id, effective_date)is best.

No, adding user_id to the index won't speed up this specific query.
Since effective_date is compared with <, the result from the index scan won't be pre-ordered by user_id, so the window function evaluation cannot benefit.  The additional column will make the index larger and consequently less efficient, so unless you can use the third index column for some other query, don't add it.
